# Deleting Mail on iOS 7 won't delete them from server

Tags: email, iphone, ios

I recently got an iPhone 5s to replace my last phone. When trying to set up the Mail app I can't figure out how to make it so when I delete an email, it also get deleted from the sever  so when I log into my account (both my accounts are @live.fr (microsoft)) on my web browser the mail is deleted too.

I've tried in the advanced settings of the accounts to set the option `Delete from server` on `Once deleted from the inbox` (approximate translation since my UI is in french) but this doesn't work (The mail is deleted on the iPhone, but still exist in the inbox when I log on my web browser).

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are there any settings on the _server_ side you can adjust? In GMail, I can choose what happens when an IMAP client marks a message as deleted. The options are _Immediately update the server_ and _Wait for the client to update the server_. There are also options for _Archive the message_, _Move the message to the Trash_, and _Immediately delete the message forever_. Although I don't know much about live.com email, these GMail options tells me that there's more to "deleting" and email than meets the eye.

Comment: @VidarRamdal going to check that. But on my Old 3Gs I never had to do something like this and it works properly

Comment: @VidarRamdal after checking on my account the setting whch say "If mail deleted on another device, delete on server too" is enabled for POP

Comment: Is there a similar setting for IMAP? I would guess that's what the iPhone mail app is using.

Comment: @VidarRamdal Yes there is but iPhone support both IMAP and POP (I was using POP before) I checked the server and port on the Outlook page dedicated to this and I use the correct one so for the moment I have no clue at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to delete & reinstall your email account through iOS `Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Add Account` select whatever email provider you have. This should also sync back up with the email providers server.

Some people that originally had hotmail (now outlook) have had similar problems and a reinstall has worked.

This behaviour may also be a result of your desktop using Post Office Protocol ([POP3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol)). Essentially if you are using the POP3 protocol (which many email providers do support, including Microsoft & Google), each system you have linked email to will download a copy of the email from the server, thus you don't have one email, rather you have *x* amount of copies. To get this how you want it, I would set up [IMAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) and make sure your devices are using the same protocols.

Comment: Oh my... live adress must be added as outlook account (even though it suggest an outlook adress) and so all the parameters are good. I added mine as "other" and set up the servers parameters manually which was almost good except the sync. I've added with the outlook setup and it works like a charm. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

On the iPhone email screen, after deleting a message, pull down from the top of the screen, thereby communicating with the server that the message has been deleted.